# Does compactness imply measurability?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{L})$ be a measurable space, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. Then,

1. $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ compact $\Rightarrow X\in\mathcal{L}$

Let $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then,

2. $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ compact $\Rightarrow X\in\mathcal{B}$

**Are (1) & (2) true statements?** If we replace *compact* for *closed*, are (1) & (2) true?

**Bonus question**: When we say that a set $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is Lebesgue (or Borel) measurable, what we mean is that $X\in\mathcal{L}$ (or $X\in\mathcal{B}$), correct?

Comment: Every closed set is the complement of an open set. With that in mind, it's probably best for you to review the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra. It will also be useful that the borel $\sigma$-algebra contains all the open sets by definition. As for the bonus question, you're exactly right. We say a set $X$ is "$\mathcal{A}$ measurable" for a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ exactly when $X \in \mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes to both, trivially, because closed sets (being the complement of open sets which are by definition in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) are Borel and hence Lebesgue measurable.

And yes to the "bonus question", just as $O$ open is the same as $O \in \mathcal{T}$ for a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$.